# Is this the smallest Prolog program whose halting is unknown?

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics, logical-purity

It is unknown whether the following 6-clause "pure" Prolog program halts.

```
:- f(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(s(N)))))))),F), m(S,S,s(F)).
    
f(o,s(o)).   
f(s(N),G) :- f(N,F), m(s(N),F,G).

m(o,_,o).    
m(s(X),Y,Z) :- a(Y,P,Z), m(X,Y,P).

a(o,Y,Y).
a(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- a(X,Y,Z).
```

It is based on a conjecture, related to [Brocard's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem), that n!+1=m^2 only has solutions for n < 8.

Is there a smaller Prolog program whose halting is unknown?

Only "pure" Prolog is allowed, so library and standard predicates, numbers, not and cut are forbidden.

I examined many unsolved problems but could not find a corresponding smaller program. Brocard's Problem is also one of the smallest in:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/97004/does-the-code-terminate

EDIT:  Determining if a program halts can be challenging. I moved an example to a new Question.

Comment: Is the `b` in `f(f(b))` intended?

Comment: Yes, if it is replaced with f(f(a)) then the program halts after a few steps. I'm glad to see you investigating this. I will be interested if you get a simple proof of non-halting.

Comment: Your use of the term *halting*. In the context of Prolog it is rather universal and existential termination. Are you aware of the literature on it?

Comment: You really should make your edit a separate question where you are asking why this program does not terminate. SO has quite strict rules on such (that's why your question was also closed in the beginning).

Comment: ... as promise: you will get a very short proof.

Comment: By _halting_ I mean standard Prolog procedural semantics: sequential order of clauses and left-to-right order of clauses in the body. A link to the literature is welcome. Thanks for your suggestion about making a separate question - I will do that in future. I look forward to your very short proof.

Comment: So where is your question? Here on SO we have to stick to SO-rules. One question and the answers for it. Hijacking an existing question for something else is not welcome here.

Comment: I moved the question to: "Does this Prolog program have a simple proof of halting?"

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a smaller Prolog program whose halting is unknown?

It all depends on your metrics of program size. If you just take the number of clauses (or literals) but do not take the size of terms into account, then the answer is yes, there are such programs. A Turing machine can be encoded with a single (recursive) binary rule and one fact. And since you are only interested in halting, the fact is not even needed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42233085/772868) for the (idea of) the encoding.

Comment: I believe that the total number of symbols is an appropriate metric.

Comment: You would need to define that more precisely

Comment: How about counting total number of occurences of predicates, constants, functions and variables?

Comment: Erdős–Moser comes close, but yours is shorter...

Answer (score 0):

I found a smaller Prolog program based on an unsolved problem found at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453225/are-these-equations-solvable-in-positive-integers. The equation is `y(x^3 - z^2) = z`. I added some s's to avoid trivial solutions.

```
:- mul(X,X,X2), mul(X,X2,X3),      % generate x^3
   add(s(V),Q,X3), mul(Z,Z,s(V)),  % z^2 + q = x^3 (ensure z > 0)
   mul(Y,Q,Z).                     % does q | z?

mul( o,    _, o ).
mul( s(X), Y, Z ) :-  add(Y,XY,Z), mul(Y,X,XY).

add( o,    Y, Y    ).
add( s(X), Y, s(Z) ) :- add(X,Y,Z).
```